# Direct access class member access with clone

Tags: php, syntax, php-5.4

As of PHP 5.4 we can use this kind of syntax:

```
$oYesterday = (new \DateTime())->modify('-1 day');
```

So we don't have to create a temp variable. I was wondering why it doesn't work with [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php), it leads to a parse error:

```
$oDayBefore = (clone $oYesterday)->modify('-1 day');

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in PHP < 7, everything in the parser was essentially a hard-coded special case, and nobody has bothered to write the case for `(clone $var)`. PHP 7 finally sports a real [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), where such things [are possible](https://3v4l.org/TcrHa).